# jquery works in chrome and firefox, not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

this won't work in IE... any ideas? When clicked it just loads the new page

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/js/photos_fb_manage.js"></script>    
<ul class="photoList">
    <li id="k877575065600">
    <a href="/mem_fb_addphotos.php?addphoto.php?fbpid=877575065600&album=837932838940" id="877575065600" class="fbpm">
    <img src="http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc4/155193_877575065600_22912405_47840445_3804175_s.jpg" />
    <span>Add To Profile</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.fbpm').click(function(e)
        {
            fbpid = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).find('span').text('PHOTO ADDED');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
            $('#addedPhotos').show();
            $('<img src="images/loading.gif" id="loadimg" />').appendTo('#addedPhotos');

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "php/ajax/photos_fb_manage.php",
               data: "fbp="+ fbpid +"",
               success: function(msg){
                $('#loadimg').remove();
                $('<img src="'+ msg +'" />').appendTo('#addedPhotos');
               }
             });

            e.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```

Comment: `s/event.returnValue =/return`. Basically, use "return false" at the end of your function instead of assigning the event's return value. (assuming the issue is it not halting when clicked, since everything else looks good. [well, except that you're explicitly using html in strings, but that's just personal preference])

Comment: In IE it loads the page and doesn't even seem to call on the click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code inside a `<script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.fbpm').click(function(e)
        {
            fbpid = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).find('span').text('PHOTO ADDED');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
            $('#addedPhotos').show();
            $('<img src="images/loading.gif" id="loadimg" />').appendTo('#addedPhotos');

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "php/ajax/photos_fb_manage.php",
               data: "fbp="+ fbpid +"",
               success: function(msg){
                $('#loadimg').remove();
                $('<img src="'+ msg +'" />').appendTo('#addedPhotos');
               }
             });

            e.preventDefault();

        });
    });

</script>
```

I assume firefox/chrome quietly go "Oh you forgot the script tag. I'll fix that for you"

Answer (score 0):

move this  `e.preventDefault();`  here

```
$('.fbpm').click(function(e)
    {
e.preventDefault();
```

remove this

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

Comment: No errors. It jus doesn't call the click function when clicked. Removed event.returnValude = false and no difference,

Comment: @Praveen-Prasad any more ideas?

Comment: @cdogmx: few things you may try, make sure in this tag '<ul class="photoList">' the word 'class' is written in lowercase, then replace this "$('.fbpm').click(function(e)" with $('.fbpm').bind('click',function(){}). Let me this works or not.

Comment: @Praveen-Prasad I got it working and i feel so dumb. I had included the script with script type as application/javascript instead of text/javascript. Thank your for all your time and help =)

Answer (score 0):

Switched javascript type from application/javascript to text/javascript and it fixed it